# Display a small image at the top-right corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK, so basically this is what I want to do but - since I'm not such a wizard with CSS - I'll need some input...

- I want to create a new class
- When this class is applied to an item (a `div` or whatever - obviously of adequate dimensions so that it fits), a small *clickable* pre-defined image is displayed at the Top-Right corner *inside* this item

How should I go about this? Any ideas?

Comment: Hey everybody, what is so absolutely horrible about this question that it has received 3 downvotes already?

Comment: @cars10 I wish I knew... lol

Comment: Though you can create a element by adding a simple class but you can't make it clickable. It must be done dynamically using javascript. AFAIK.

Comment: HTML and CSS won't have everything that you need. Depending on what kind of event you'll want along with that click you'll need jquery/javascript.

Comment: @Mr_Green I wasn't asking how to make it "clickable" - that was just a sidenote... :-)

Comment: Since clickable was in bold I assumed it was part of the emphasis of the question.

Comment: @gersande The project I'm currently working is far too complex to elaborate - but it already contains LOTS of jquery, jquery mobile, objective-c, html, css... What I need help with is the CSS part :-)

Comment: @gersande Yep, mea culpa! Just noticed.

Comment: You can do this using `:after` or `:before` pseudo selectors to the class which you want to add..

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon maybe you should add a [jQuery] tag to your question to "allow" everybody to come up with a "complete" answer ... ;-) (they all feel kind of shy using anything that is not *explictely* mentioned as tag in the post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="hasicon">
    <img src="blah.jpg" class="icon" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon { display: none; }
.hasicon { position: relative; }
.hasicon .icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.hasicon > .icon', function() {
    // do something
});
```

To use this, simply add class `hasicon` to the div. Those divs without the class will not display the icon.

**UPDATE:**

You could try using an empty span, if it suits your requirements better:

```
<div class="hasicon">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hasicon { position: relative; }
.hasicon > span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('myImage.png') center no-repeat;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.hasicon > span', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible to totally eliminate the `<img>` part from the HTML and make it totally css-dependent?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon the minimal requirements would be to use an empty span.

Comment: Hmm... Well, *that* looks like an interesting suggestion. Give me a sec to try this out! Thanks! :-)

Comment: You will have to find a way to make the `span` clickable, which i think is possible.

Comment: @gersande Yes, with a span, you can simply set a click handler using jQuery. I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Image not being displayed:

```
<div class="DivWithImage">
    <img src="blah.jpg" class="thumbIMG">
</div>
```

Image being displayed:

```
<div class="DivWithImage">
    <img src="blah.jpg" class="thumbIMG shown">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.DivWithImage .thumbIMG{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display:none;
}
.DivWithImage .thumbIMG.shown{
    display:block;
}
```

You then need to use javascript to apply or remove the class `shown`.

Comment: I made a mistake. There's no spaces between `.thumbIMG .hidden`, because they are 2 classes on the same element.

Comment: Would it be possible to totally eliminate the `<img>` part from the HTML and make it totally css-dependent?

Comment: What do you want to trigger the image to be displayed? CSS has a little bit of dynamic page altering.

Comment: You can have the image displayed in the background through css, but it wont be "clickable".

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Do you want something like this? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/NV9B5/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:after` and `:before` pseudo selectors to the class which you are adding dynamically.

**HTML**

```
<div class="something dynamicallyAdded"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dynamicallyAdded {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}
.dynamicallyAdded:after {
    content:"";
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: red;
} 

/* if you want the hover effect */
.dynamicallyAdded:hover:after {
    content:"";
    background-color: green;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/NV9B5/1/)

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/NV9B5/2/)** (*with an image*)